# Jenkins Bitbucket Credentials Cannot read repo

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

Jenkins Bitbucket Credentials Cannot read repo

I want to read the Bitbucket repo from Jenkins through Git.
I did provide the Bitbucket URL in Maven integration project and provide my username and password to it, but unfortunately it cannot read the repo. I don't know what wrong with it. Anyone can enlighten me.

The Error is

```
Failed to connect to repository : 
Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe ls-remote -h -- https://nicholasWongKC@bitbucket.org/mediaprimadigital/butv3-automation-testing.git HEAD" returned 
status code 128: stdout: stderr: fatal: Cannot prompt because user interactivity has been disabled. 
remote: Login failed due to incorrect login credentials or method. 
remote: If you are unsure of which login details or login method to use, visit: 
remote: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/log-into-or-connect-to-bitbucket-cl
```

How to solve this error? I am totally a beginner in Jenkins. Please help me.

PS: I have used the Jenkins credential helper which is username and password but still there is error pop out.

I tried with my personal GitHub repo, and it is working perfectly, but when I am using company Bitbucket repo, it displays error.

I had tried with Bitbucket Personal Access Token, but it doesn't display it.

May I know what wrong with it?

Comment: How is the Git command initiated? Is this a declarative or freestyle pipeline?

Comment: I don;t understand your questions. I input the git exe path into the Global configuration.

Comment: Where do you pull the repo?

Comment: In the build job i input the git repo address?

Comment: Can you access the repo from outside Jenkins? Have the credentials been set properly?

Comment: Yes. Do I need to install bitbucket server integration? https://plugins.jenkins.io/atlassian-bitbucket-server-integration/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-FugzVYJQU

Comment: I added the https://bitbucket.org/mediaprimadigital but it says This plugin does not support connecting to bitbucket.org. It is for Bitbucket Server instances only. Why is it like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253857/discussion-between-m-b-and-nicholas).

Comment: you may also consider using ssh instead of https to access your repo
connfigure keys as described here

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-personal-ssh-keys-on-windows/

and then use repo with ssh url (should be something like this):

git clone git@bitbucket.org:nicholasWongKC/mediaprimadigital/butv3-automation-testing.git

Answer (score 2):

In a Jenkins job "source control" configuration, it is best to use the URL alone, without authentication:

```
https://bitbucket.org/mediaprimadigital/butv3-automation-testing.git
```

Then make sure to [select the right credential](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/b96f366e7badeedaf69724991e44409be11a07b6/docs/user.adoc#using-credentials) for this repository:

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/b96f366e7badeedaf69724991e44409be11a07b6/docs/images/select-or-expr-as-select.png]

You will have defined that credential first:

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/b96f366e7badeedaf69724991e44409be11a07b6/docs/images/select-add-dialog.png]

Do use the credential username and *token* (PAT) not password.

That should inject both `username:token` in your HTTPS URL, making sure Git will not try to ask for your password as it did when only the username was in the URL.